# DBgrid not showing changes and show error when to try update - Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I have the following code;

```
    unit UNewCar;

    interface

    uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
    System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask,
    Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Data.Win.ADODB, Datasnap.DBClient,
    Vcl.ExtCtrls;

    type
      TFNewCar = class(TForm)
      ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
      ADOQueryTC: TADOQuery;
     DataSourceTC: TDataSource;
     ADOQueryCC: TADOQuery;
     DataSourceCC: TDataSource;

     DBLookupComboBox1: TDBLookupComboBox;
     Label1: TLabel;
     Label2: TLabel;
     BtnNew: TButton;
     BtnSave: TButton;
     DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
     ADOQueryTCCusID: TAutoIncField;
     ADOQueryTCName: TWideStringField;
     ADOQueryTCCName: TWideStringField;
     ADOQueryTCAdd: TWideMemoField;
     ADOQueryTCCity: TWideStringField;
     ADOQueryTCPhone: TWideStringField;
     ADOQueryTCEmail: TWideStringField;
     ADOQueryCCName: TWideStringField;
     ADOQueryCCCusID: TIntegerField;
     ADOQueryCCCar: TWideStringField;
     DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
     procedure BtnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
     procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
     procedure btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
     procedure ADOQueryCCBeforeEdit(DataSet: TDataSet);
     procedure ADOQueryCCBeforeInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
     procedure ADOQueryCCBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
   private
    procedure CheckSaveButtonClicked;
    function GetSaveEnabled: Boolean;
    procedure SetSaveEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
  protected
   public
    SaveClicked : Boolean;
    property SaveEnabled : Boolean read GetSaveEnabled write SetSaveEnabled;
    end;

   var
    FNewCar: TFNewCar;

   implementation

   {$R *.dfm}

   procedure TFNewCar.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
  SaveEnabled := False;
  ADOQueryCC.Open;
  ADOQueryTC.Open;
  ADOQueryCC.Requery;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.ADOQueryCCBeforeEdit(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  SaveEnabled := True;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.ADOQueryCCBeforeInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  SaveEnabled := True;
  DBEdit1.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.ADOQueryCCBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  CheckSaveButtonClicked;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.CheckSaveButtonClicked;
begin
  if not SaveClicked then begin
    AdoQueryCC.Cancel;
    Abort;   //  In case the user clicked the DBNavigator Save button
  end;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveClicked := True;
  if DBEdit1.Text = '' then
    begin
     ShowMessage('Please enter the missing data!');
    end
    else
    begin
    AdoQueryCC.Post;
    SaveEnabled := False;
    ADOQueryCC.close;
    ADOQueryCC.SQL.text:='SELECT tcustomer.Name,  tcustomercar.CusID,  tcustomercar.Car FROM tcustomer, tcustomercar WHERE tcustomer.CusID = tcustomercar.CusID';
    ADOQueryCC.Open;
    end;
end;

function TFNewCar.GetSaveEnabled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := btnSave.Enabled;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.SetSaveEnabled(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  btnSave.Enabled := Value;
  SaveClicked := False;
end;

procedure TFNewCar.BtnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOQueryCC.Insert;
end;

end.
```

Following in AdoqueryCC =>SQL

```
SELECT tcustomer.Name,  tcustomercar.CusID,  tcustomercar.Car FROM tcustomer, tcustomercar WHERE tcustomer.CusID = tcustomercar.CusID
```

When my form FNewCar loaded **it does not have the recent changes** even i try to use Requery and refresh in create an event. FNewCar form allows users to **enter new record (cars) successfully** but when **try to update a field**  following error appear as well "
Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing"

What i am doing wrong???

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auwwa.png)

Comment: Leaving aside the recent changes issue, on what **exact** line of your code do you get the "Insufficient key column" error?  If it is not in your q already, you need to add the code of the method in which the error occurs.

Comment: You're missing a primary key.

Comment: @MartynA The error comes only when i try to edit and press save button it shows me the error. if you see Screenshot attached i am using a DBLookupComoBox.

Comment: @Victoria what you mean i am missing PK, it is in my table and foreign key as well. can you please more specific!

Comment: Why Someone discouraging me to ask questions, my second question mark as negative rate really just block me if you like me

Comment: You're selecting from 2 tables. Into those 2 tables you're trying to insert a row (`ADOQueryCC.Insert`). Thus (and it's a wild guess because I was not doing this ever), you need to have a composite index in your query object specified (but it's my guess). And that table must be in relationship 1:1, of course. From your description I'm a bit lost. Could you provide a minimal compilable example (including schema creation), please (I think this kind of insert will be problematic in general)? Downvote is not mine (I would upvote if I could reproduce)...

Comment: @Victoria thank you for your reply. this error is not because of ADOQueryC.Insert because the insert function is working well the issue is only appear when i try to edit and existing record.

Comment: Editing means changing the field 'Car' in the 'Car Master' form's grid? Is 'Car' part of the primary key in table 'CustomerCar'?

Comment: Yes Car belongs to tcustomercar table and have Primary key and FK with tcustomer table

Comment: You are asking why you are getting downvotes.  It is because your q is off-topic at the moment because you do not provide sufficient inform for readers to be able to answer.  @Victoria is extremely good at answering questions, but even she is having to guess what you are doing.  Readers should not have to guess.  As she has said, you should provide an MCVE - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MartynA can you check now the update on my original question above if I'm not making another mistake and Thank you for your Guide.

Comment: Soory, you shouldn't expect SO readers to download material from external sources - it could be mined with any sort of malware.  Your q here should be self-contained.  Find and follow the SO link about "How to ask a queston".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *Here's a link to somewhere else. Please go there, figure out what my problem is, and then come back here and give me a solution* is not how this site works. The **relevant** code must be here, in your question itself. See [ask] and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then come back and [edit] your post to provide the **minimal code** that will allow us to reproduce the problem. If you can't do so, then your question is most likely not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that:

> does not have the recent changes

is because the data has not been posted. And cannot be from what I can see. You're trying to insert and update tuples from two tables, but you fetched only a foreign key of a detail table. Imagine, that you'd like to update this resultset (even manually by some SQL command tool):

```sql
SELECT
   Customer.Name,
   CustomerCar.CusID,
   CustomerCar.Car
FROM
   Customer, CustomerCar
WHERE
   Customer.CusID = CustomerCar.CusID
```

You could update **CustomerCar** table:

```sql
UPDATE CustomerCar SET Car = 'NewValue' WHERE CusID = <Fetched CustomerCar.CusID>
```

because you fetched its unique foreign key in the **CustomerCar.CusID** column, whilst you couldn't update **Customer** table:

```sql
UPDATE Customer SET Name = 'NewValue' WHERE <What?>
```

because you didn't fetch any unique primary key. And at the same situation is the engine, I guess. I only guess, but I don't believe that there are fetched any metadata for the **WHERE** clause (which is the only place where you could get the unique primary key for the **Customer** table). Yes, you could cheat with an SQL command tool and use the key fetched for the other table, but client engines are not that smart, I must add.

You received this error:

> Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing

because ADO doesn't know which record should update (or refresh) because of the missing unique identifier for both tables (primary unique keys you missed to fetch).

My advice for possible solution is simple, just fetch primary unique keys for both tables (**CusCarID** is a made up primary unique key of the **CustomerCar** table):

```sql
SELECT
   Customer.CusID,
   Customer.Name,
   CustomerCar.CusCarID,
   CustomerCar.Car
FROM
   Customer, CustomerCar
WHERE
   Customer.CusID = CustomerCar.CusID
```

Comment: I was trying to answer the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45481764/1).

Comment: I rolled back the question to its original state.

Comment: @Victoria, I have deleted my comment and you got an upvote for a very good answer. BTW, ADO is capable of dealing with updates on  joined queries provding you specify `ds.Properties['Update Criteria'] := adCriteriaKey` and `Properties['Unique Table'] := 'TheTable'` (there might be more properties involved which I currently do not recall) and it has a Key to update on. If OP would have made an effort with MCVE, it could actually be a very good *question* too.

Comment: @Victoria i am just new to programming really thank you now it's working fine. in SQL now i call both tables PK and FK in 2nd tabel (tcustomercar) update the DBLookupComboBox=>DataField as tcustomercar.CusID instead CusID.

Comment: @kobik, thank you very much! Never heard about these (they are actually _hints_ for what cannot be obtained from the original query). Fiaz, glad it helped. Maybe if you try to craft an MCVE, others like kobik might give you better answer (I'm just a FireDAC guy, not ADO specialist :)

Comment: @Victoria One issue i still not able figure it out, i have one DBLookupComboBox1 which appears on my second form. The changes i do on my first form didn't appear in my DBLookupComboBox1. i treid already  DBLookupListBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Close;
  DBLookupListBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Open; and refresh option as well. any suggestion????